# Automate imports from same directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this file, which imports and mounts routes from `components/*` directory.

Is there any way I could automate this?

```
// Middlewares
const authorizeMiddleware = require('../middlewares/authorize');
const authMiddleware = require('../middlewares/auth');

// load components
const aclComponent = require('../components/acl/acl.component');
const jobComponent = require('../components/job/job.component');
const zoneComponent = require('../components/zone/zone.component');
const authComponent = require('../components/auth/auth.component');
const cityComponent = require('../components/city/city.component');
const usersComponent = require('../components/user/user.component');
..
...
.....

function loadRoutes(router) {
  router.use(
    '/auth',
    authComponent.AuthRoutes,
  );

  router.use(
    '/users',
    usersComponent.UsersRoutes,
  );
  
  ..
  ...
  ....
  return router;
}

module.exports = loadRoutes;
```

I have seen such things in `typeorm` where it search for entities based on patterns.

Something similar to this,

```
{
  "entities": ["dist/entity/**/*.js"],
  "migrations": ["dist/migration/**/*.js"],
  "subscribers": ["dist/subscriber/**/*.js"],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
    "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
  }
```

Can this be achieved with this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)?

Comment: its certainly possible to load up files in nodejs dynamically (personally I did this years ago and opted out of it later because it makes your code brittle, the explicitness of declaring dependencies makes your code better, especially if you use a linter like eslint or standardjs)

Comment: What do you mean by it makes code brittle? Does it make testing hard? Or does it reduce readability?

Comment: both, but also any linting tool that you use will break, which is a bedrock for developers

Comment: My thoughts on this:

1. Set up a place for your dynamic configuration (e.g. a regular expression, directory, etc.)
2. Read configuration, find files that meet the configuration
3. Iterating over the files found, export an import library file --- say `dynamic.js` either during your startup process, your build process, or the start of your app.
4. Finally, where you need it, `const lib = require('dynamic')`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `glob.js` and it did the work,

```
const glob = require('glob');
const path = require('path');

// Use the glob package to match all files ending in ".component.js" in the "components" directory
const componentFiles = glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'components', '**', '*.component.js'));

function loadRoutes(router) {
  // Iterate over the matched files and require each one
  componentFiles.forEach((componentFile) => {
    const component = require(componentFile);

    // Extract the component name from the file name (e.g. "acl.component.js" => "acl")
    const componentName = path.basename(componentFile, '.component.js');

    // Mount the routes for the component on the router using the component name as the base path
    router.use(`/${componentName}`, component.Routes);
  });

  return router;
}

module.exports = loadRoutes;
```